# Decoder in Java

Tags: java

I have a java file that encodes a file into something else. I was wondering if there was a way to decode it.

I run the file 3 times, then I add a slash to the begining of the .txt file and run it one more time. It takes

```
"Hello World! This is the Computer!
Say Hi!"
```

and gives

> "
>   c
>   f
>   e
>   -1
>   -1
>   -1
>   '#:-52'
>   '#:-44'
>   '#:-47'
>   f
>   g
>   d
>   -1
>   -1
>   -1"

The code is the following:

```
package complexify;

public class Complexer {
public void Complex() {
    ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
    FileWriter f = new FileWriter();
    NumToChar n = new NumToChar();
    String oldContents = r.readFile("C:/Users/Work and PA/Desktop/Java Projects/Complexify/src/complexify/TextFile.txt");
    String newContents = "";
    String newContentsTemp = "";
    char[] contentsChar = oldContents.toCharArray();
    int letterPos = 0;
    boolean complex = false;
    if (contentsChar[0] == '/') {
        complex = false;
        //contentsChar[0] = '_';
    }
    else {
        complex = true;
    }
    if (complex == true) {
        for (int i = 0;i < contentsChar.length;i++) {
            char currentChar = contentsChar[i];
            letterPos = currentChar - 'a';
            newContents += letterPos + ",";
            newContentsTemp += letterPos + ",";
            if (newContentsTemp.length() == 100) {
                newContents += "\n";
                newContentsTemp = "";
            }
        }
        try {
            newContents = newContents.substring(0, newContents.length()-7);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    if (complex == false) {
        for (int i = 0;i < contentsChar.length;i++) {
            char currentChar = contentsChar[i];
            if (currentChar == ',') {
                System.out.println(newContentsTemp);
                try {
                    newContents += (n.getCharForNumber(Integer.parseInt(newContentsTemp)));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            else {
                newContentsTemp += currentChar;
                if (newContentsTemp.length() == 100) {
                    newContents += "\n";
                    newContentsTemp = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newContents);
    f.write(newContents);
}
```

}

```
package complexify;

public class ComplexifyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Complexer c = new Complexer();
    c.Complex();
}
```

}

```
package complexify;
```

import java.io.*;

public class FileWriter {

```
public void write(String text) {
      String fileName = "C:/Users/Work and PA/Desktop/Java Projects/Complexify/src/complexify/TextFile.txt";

      try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "utf-8"))) {
          writer.write(text);
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + fileName + "'");
      }
}
```

}

```
package complexify;

public class NumToChar {
public String getCharForNumber(int i) {
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    char[] capAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    if (i > -1) {
        if (i > 25) {
            return "-1";
        }
        else {
            return Character.toString(alphabet[i]);
        }
    }
    //Capital Letters
    else if (i > -33 && i < -6) {
        i = i + 32;
        return Character.toString(capAlphabet[i]);
    }
    else {
        return "'#:" + i + "'";
    }
}
```

}

```
package complexify;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile {
public String readFile(String file) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String contents = "";
    try {

        File f = new File(file);

        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            contents += sCurrentLine;
            contents += "\n";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return contents;

}
```

}

Sorry for the formatting issues and thanks!

Comment: It is certainly possible, but we are not here to write the code for you. Have a go yourself at trying to implement the reverse of the code you have. Once you have done that, post your solution with any specific questions you have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post. I have changed complex to encode.  And I have formatted the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Wheater a code or not can be decoded depends on a variety of factors. As a rule of thump, if every input-letter can only be converted to exactly one other letter and one output-letter can only be produced by one input letter at a given position, then the code can be decoded.

```
if (i > 25) {
   return "-1";
}
```

makes it impossible to distinguish any number above 25 from any other number above 25 and your output code contain -1 which seems to indicate you cannot decode those characters again.

Your programm-code looks a little bit confuse. You should consider putting the parts into smaller methods and give the methods proper names. This will make your code more readable. Currently everything you do is more or less done in 1-2 methods and your code seems to be redundant and buggy.

Also your code seems to cut of the last 7 letters of your input string

```
newContents = newContents.substring(0, newContents.length()-7);
```

So my guess is the code can't be restored to the full input message.

Comment: The reason for  cutting the last seven letters is because, for some reason that I could not figure out, it would always add the number '-87' on to the end of the string.